# Endomorphism rings of flat group schemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, arithmetic-geometry, elliptic-curves, etale-cohomology

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $X$ be a flat $R$-group scheme.

We call $\text{End}_R(X)$ the ring of endomorphisms of the $R$-group scheme $X$, defined over $R$.

Let $R\to S$ be a ring map satisfying a property $(P)$.

> **Question 1:** For what $(P)$ is the induced ring homomorphism
>   $$\text{End}_R(X)\to\text{End}_S(X_S)$$
>
> - injective
> - surjective?

**Example:** Let $p$ be a prime, $E$ a supersingular elliptic curve over $\textbf{F}_p$.
Let $R=\textbf{F}_p$, $S=\textbf{F}_{p^2}$, $T = \overline{\textbf{F}}_p$, $X=E$. Then $\text{End}_R(X)\to\text{End}_S(X_S)$ is injective, and $\text{End}_S(X_S)\to\text{End}_T(X_T)$ is an isomorphism.

From this example it would appear that injectivity can be read off some property of $R\to S$, such as flatness/faithful flatness, but surjectivity has little to do with $R\to S$ and highly depends on $X$ instead.

> **Question 2:** is there an example of $X, R\to S$ such that the ring map:
>   $$\text{End}_R(X)\to\text{End}_S(X_S)$$
>   is **not** injective?

Comment: The map $\operatorname{End}_R(X) \to \operatorname{End}_S(X_S)$ is always injective if $R \to S$ is faithfully flat and $X$ is of finite presentation over $R$. Without any assumptions on $R \to S$ it's easy to make counterexamples, for example if $X = \mathbf G_a$ and $R \to S$ is $\mathbf Z_p \to \mathbf F_p$. I think similar examples might exist if $R \to S$ is flat, but it's a bit harder to make examples.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn Thanks! Indeed I was aware of the faithfully flat $R\to S$ case with $X$ finitely presented: as you say I'm trying to come up with an example for failure of injectivity when $R\to S$ is flat. I should say Q1 was designed to hopefully suggest a general recipe to produce answers to Q2

Comment: One thing you can try is to study $X = \mathbf G_a$ over rings like $R = k[x,y]/(xy,y^2)$ that have embedded primes. Then there is an open $S = R[x^{-1}] = k[x,x^{-1}]$ such that the inclusion $R \to S$ is not injective, and this should give an endomorphism $t \mapsto t+y$ of $X_R$ that maps to the identity on $X_S$.

Comment: If $X$ is noncommutative, how do you get a ring of endomorphisms?